# Can two Jenkins controllers use the same agents?

Tags: jenkins, multiple-instances, jenkins-agent

I plan for second Jenkins instance tests that our jobs all work with the latest Jenkins and plugins version.

**Can two Jenkins instance use the same agents?**

so there would not be any conflicts/bugs in recent and 1-year-old Jenkins versions.